# Unable to send SMS using AT Commands

Tags: c++, qt, sms, usb, at-command

I am using `QextSerialPort` to access ports

```
#include <qstring.h>
#include <qdebug.h>
#include <QCoreApplication>



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QList<QextPortInfo> ports = QextSerialEnumerator::getPorts();
    QextSerialPort *port;
    QString portName;

    int counter=0;

    //Navigate through ports untill you find huwawei USB dongle
    while(counter<ports.size())
    {
     portName = ports[counter].portName;
    QString productId= ports[counter].productID;
    QString physicalName = ports[counter].physName;
    QString vendorId = ports[counter].vendorID;
    QString friendName = ports[counter].friendName;


    string convertedPortName = portName.toLocal8Bit().constData();
    string convertedProductId = productId.toLocal8Bit().constData();
    string convertedPhysicalName = physicalName.toLocal8Bit().constData();
    string convertedVendorId = vendorId.toLocal8Bit().constData();
    string convertedFriendName = friendName.toLocal8Bit().constData();

    cout << "Port Name: " << convertedPortName << endl;
    cout << "Product ID:" << convertedProductId << endl;
    cout << "Physical Name: " << convertedPhysicalName << endl;
    cout << "Vendor Id: " << convertedVendorId << endl;
    cout << "Friend Name: " << convertedFriendName << endl;
    cout << endl;
    counter++;


    //Break if you found Huwawei USB dongle, assign the port to a new port

    if (std::string::npos != convertedFriendName.find("HUAWEI Mobile Connect - 3G Modem"))
    {
      std::cout << "found!" << std::endl;
      port = new QextSerialPort(portName);
      break;
    }
    }


    //Write and send the SMS
    port->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite) ;
    cout << port->isOpen() << endl;
    port->write("AT+CFUN=1");
    port->write("AT+CMGF=1 ");
    port->write("AT+CMGS=1234567");
    port->write("Hello Test SMS");
    //port->write("0x1A");
    port->flush();

    port->close();
    cout << port->isOpen() << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

In this code, I am trying to send SMS using AT commands. My dongle is a Huawei USB dongle. It's known as "MegaFone Modem" anyway.

In my code, I am unable to send any SMS actually. Why is that? Please note you have to edit the phone number when you run this code. I am very new to QT, USB Programming and AT commands. I even don't know whether I am accessing the correct port, because there are 3 ports belong to Huawei. My output is as follows.

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
#include <qstring.h>
#include <qdebug.h>
#include <QCoreApplication>



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QList<QextPortInfo> ports = QextSerialEnumerator::getPorts();
    QextSerialPort *port;
    QString portName;

    int counter=0;

    //Navigate through ports untill you find huwawei USB dongle
    while(counter<ports.size())
    {
     portName = ports[counter].portName;
    QString productId= ports[counter].productID;
    QString physicalName = ports[counter].physName;
    QString vendorId = ports[counter].vendorID;
    QString friendName = ports[counter].friendName;


    string convertedPortName = portName.toLocal8Bit().constData();
    string convertedProductId = productId.toLocal8Bit().constData();
    string convertedPhysicalName = physicalName.toLocal8Bit().constData();
    string convertedVendorId = vendorId.toLocal8Bit().constData();
    string convertedFriendName = friendName.toLocal8Bit().constData();

    cout << "Port Name: " << convertedPortName << endl;
    cout << "Product ID:" << convertedProductId << endl;
    cout << "Physical Name: " << convertedPhysicalName << endl;
    cout << "Vendor Id: " << convertedVendorId << endl;
    cout << "Friend Name: " << convertedFriendName << endl;
    cout << endl;
    counter++;


    //Break if you found Huwawei USB dongle, assign the port to a new port

    if (std::string::npos != convertedFriendName.find("HUAWEI Mobile Connect - 3G Modem"))
    {
      std::cout << "found!" << std::endl;
      port = new QextSerialPort(portName);
      break;
    }
    }


    //Write and send the SMS
    port->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite) ;
    cout << port->isOpen() << endl;
    port->write("AT+CFUN=1\n");
    cout << "\n";
    port->write("AT+CMGF=1 \n ");
    cout << "\n";
    port->write("AT+CMGS=0776255495\n");
    cout << "\n";
    port->write("Hello Test SMS\n");
    cout << "\n";
    //port->write("0x1A");
    port->flush();

    port->close();
    cout << port->isOpen() << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Did you look here and try this program first? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/120638/3G-Modem-Internet-Dialer

Comment: Have you read V.250 yet? You are terminating the commands with "\n" which is wrong, V.250 explicitly says that AT command lines should be terminated with `<CR>`, e.g. "\r" (actually the `S3` value, but that should always be 13).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the following:

```
port->write("AT+CFUN=1");
port->write("AT+CMGF=1 ");
port->write("AT+CMGS=1234567");
port->write("Hello Test SMS");
```

Always after sending a AT command line to the modem, you **MUST** wait for the final result code (e.g. typically `OK`or `ERROR` although there are some more, and you must be prepared to handle all of them. For an example of how to wait for final result codes, you can look at the source code of [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/), which is a tiny program for reading a list of AT commands, send them to the modem and print the responses).

Because without waiting the following command will abort the currently executing command. Abortion of AT commands is defined in section "5.6.1 Aborting commands" in V.250. If you have little experience with handling AT commands, that specification is a must read. Also you would do well in reading 27.005 for the +CMG... commands you use. You find links to the specifications on the [at-command tag information](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/at-command/info).

For `AT+CMGS` specifically you must also wait for "\r\n> " before sending the text, see [my other answe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15591673/23118)r.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated the code, please have a look. The given link in your answer is for a C program, which I didn't understand anything at all!

Comment: What did you not understand about the program?

Comment: I really appreciate your help here. I am unable to understand these stuff without working examples of C++. I do not know C, actually I am bit new to C++ as well.