# Send SMS using AT commands via dual SIM phone

Tags: c#, sms, serial-port, at-command

I wrote an application to send an SMS using AT commands as follows:

```
SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM40", 115200);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
_serialPort.Open();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
_serialPort.Write("AT+CMGF=1\r");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
_serialPort.Write("AT+CMGS=\"" + toPhoneNumber + "\"\r\n");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
_serialPort.Write("Test" + "\x1A");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
_serialPort.Close();
```

This code works well if the phone is installed and if a COM port number is available.

When a dual SIM phone is connected to the computer, is there any way to select the SIM to send message from?

Comment: It's not your question, but with regard to your code, please take into account the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16402403/unable-to-send-sms-using-at-commands/16404193#16404193

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard AT command defined in [the 3GPP specification.](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm)
It seems that individual device manufacturers have defined their own AT commands to choose the SIM, for example [this one.](http://www.quectel.com/UploadImage/DownloadFile/20130327114707739.pdf)

Contact the device manufacturer and ask them what they have defined for this.

Answer (score -2):

```
public string ExecCommand(SerialPort port, string command, int responseTimeout, string errorMessage)
    {
        try
        {

            port.DiscardOutBuffer();
            port.DiscardInBuffer();
            receiveNow.Reset();
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            port.Write(command + "\r");

            string input = ReadResponse(port, responseTimeout);
            if ((input.Length == 0) || ((!input.EndsWith("\r\n> ")) && (!input.Contains("\r\nOK\r\n"))))
                throw new ApplicationException("No success message was received.");
            return input;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //int a = ErrorCmd(port);
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.EventType == SerialData.Chars)
            {
                receiveNow.Set();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public string ReadResponse(SerialPort port, int timeout)
    {
        string buffer = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            do
            {
            //Thread.Sleep(5000);
            jump: if (receiveNow.WaitOne(timeout, false))
                {
                    string t = port.ReadExisting();
                    buffer += t;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (buffer.Length == 0)
                    {
                        goto jump;
                    }
                    if (buffer.Length > 0)
                    {
                        //goto jump;
                        throw new ApplicationException("Response received is incomplete.");
                    }
                    else
                        throw new ApplicationException("No data received from phone.");
                }
            }
            while (!buffer.Contains("\r\nOK\r\n") && !buffer.EndsWith("\r\n> ") && !buffer.EndsWith("\r\nERROR\r\n"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return buffer;
    }

public string ExecCommand(SerialPort port, string command, int responseTimeout, string errorMessage)
    {
        try
        {

            port.DiscardOutBuffer();
            port.DiscardInBuffer();
            receiveNow.Reset();
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            port.Write(command + "\r");

            string input = ReadResponse(port, responseTimeout);
            if ((input.Length == 0) || ((!input.EndsWith("\r\n> ")) && (!input.Contains("\r\nOK\r\n"))))
                throw new ApplicationException("No success message was received.");
            return input;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //int a = ErrorCmd(port);
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.EventType == SerialData.Chars)
            {
                receiveNow.Set();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public string ReadResponse(SerialPort port, int timeout)
    {
        string buffer = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            do
            {
            //Thread.Sleep(5000);
            jump: if (receiveNow.WaitOne(timeout, false))
                {
                    string t = port.ReadExisting();
                    buffer += t;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (buffer.Length == 0)
                    {
                        goto jump;
                    }
                    if (buffer.Length > 0)
                    {
                        //goto jump;
                        throw new ApplicationException("Response received is incomplete.");
                    }
                    else
                        throw new ApplicationException("No data received from phone.");
                }
            }
            while (!buffer.Contains("\r\nOK\r\n") && !buffer.EndsWith("\r\n> ") && !buffer.EndsWith("\r\nERROR\r\n"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return buffer;
    }
```

Comment: Please describe what your ode actually does and not just post some code ;)