# GSM Modem Mapping in linux

Tags: linux, serial-port, gsm, modem, at-command

My task is to find out which GSM modem is connected to which serial port and write a programm in python which does the following work.

Now since multiple sim cards can be connected to a given modem, my task is to find details of the sim cards which in each modems.

I use minicom to pass AT commands to the modem.

Answer (score 0):

To identify what kind of modem that is connected on a serial port, you can use AT commands

```
ATI         Request Identification Information
AT+GMI      Request Manufacturer Identification
AT+GMM      Request Model Identification
AT+GMR      Request Revision Identification
AT+GOI      Request Global Object Identification
AT+GSN      Request Product Serial Number Identification
AT+CGMI     Request Manufacturer Identification
AT+CGMM     Request Model Identification
AT+CGMR     Request Revision Identification
AT+CGSN     Request Product Serial Number Identification
AT+CIMI     Request international mobile subscriber identity
```

With regards to [determining which of dualsim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16518865/23118), there is no standardised way of doing this.

If you are really adventurous and not afraid of entering into the unintuitive and nothing-is-easily-understandable-documented land of SIM (using AT+CSIM/AT+CRSM), you could possibly find some useful information in some EF (but I mention this option more or less just for completeness...).

Comment: I am having problems with getting my device online, How to check on which serial port is the device online?
Then, how can I determine my own number using AT commands?