# At command shows busy when sms is Send again (in java)

Tags: java, gsm, at-command

```
import javax.comm.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Sms {
public synchronized static String main1(String arr) {
 char cntrlZ=(char)26;
InputStream input = null;
OutputStream output = null;
SerialPort serialPort = null;
try {
CommPortIdentifier portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM3");


serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleReadApp1", 2000);
//System.out.println("sdiosdfdsf");
String f=null;int n;
input = serialPort.getInputStream();
output = serialPort.getOutputStream();


Thread readThread;
serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

try {
serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, 
SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, 
SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
} catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {}

output.write(("ATZ\r\natH\r\n+CMGW: 0\r\n+CMGW: 1\r\n").getBytes());
output.flush();Thread.sleep(200);
output.write(("ath0\r\n").getBytes());
output.flush();Thread.sleep(200);
output.write(("AT+CMGF=1\r\n").getBytes());
output.flush();Thread.sleep(200);
output.write(("AT+CMGS=\"09629993650\"\r\n+CMGW: 20\r\n").getBytes());

output.write(("hellooopssss445 545inoo you there?").getBytes());
output.write(("\032").getBytes());
output.flush();


Thread.sleep(2000);
byte[] readBuffer = new byte[120];

try {
while (input.available() > 0) {
int numBytes = input.read(readBuffer);
}

 input.close();
 output.close();
 serialPort.removeEventListener();
serialPort.sendBreak(1000);
serialPort.getInputStream().close();
serialPort.getOutputStream().close();
if (serialPort!=null)
System.out.print("Port is not null!!!");
//serialPort.closeport();
if (serialPort!=null)
System.out.print("Port is not null!!!");
System.out.print(new String(readBuffer));


return(new String(readBuffer));
} catch (IOException e) {}
 output.flush();

} catch (NoSuchPortException e) {
System.out.println("Exception in Adding Listener" + e);
} catch (PortInUseException e) {
System.out.println("Exception in Adding Listener" + e);
} catch (IOException e) {
System.out.println("Exception in Adding Listener" + e);
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
System.out.println("Exception in Adding Listener" + e);
}
return ("fault");
}



public static void main(String[] arg) {


char ii[]=main1("").toCharArray();
for(int j=0;j<ii.length;j++)
{
if((ii[j]=='O')&&(ii[j+1]=='K'))
System.out.println("GOT");
}
}

}
```

When I compile and execute this program, message is not sent until I remove my Mobile from USB.And if I don't remove my Mobile and run the same program, Its shows Busy and CMI ERROR : 503.

And second message is never sent (when program is compiled again).Moreover Port is never closed as you can see in the program.

What can be done in this code? Please don't provide me some other program like SMSLIB rather improve/edit this code.

I'm trying this for about 3 days , still negative results.
 Please help me.I want to send Bulk SMS without disconnecting the mobile again and again.

Comment: Should I think nobody knows this answer ???
Its almost 30 hours but nobody has replied :(

Comment: Now its about 42 hours no reply!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Can any body help at this question

Answer (score 0):

You must **never** use sleep like that; you **must** read and parse the response given by the modem. Sleeping like that is only marginally better then not waiting at all (which I address in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16404193/23118)). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16446523/23118) for how to read and parse the response you get back.

BTW, an AT command should be terminated with only `\r` and not `\r\n` (unless you have changed S3, and you should not do that), see [V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en) for more details on that and AT commands in general (e.g. if you have not already read that specification it is highly recommended).