# Does AT command depend on device or its an independent API command?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, at-command, modem

I found some code on net that allow me to read/send SMS from a Mobile via bluetooth connection. But using USB EDGE modem I can't either send or read SMS. I just can connect to that modem's port.

My Code is:

```
string mobileNumber = txt_number.Text;
string smMessage = txt_message.Text;
AutoResetEvent receiveNow;
String command="";
SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
port.PortName = cmb_port.Text;
port.Open();
command = "AT+CMGF=1";
port.WriteLine(command);
command = "AT+CMGS=\"" + mobileNumber + "\"";
port.WriteLine(command);
command = smMessage + char.ConvertFromUtf32(26) + "\r";
port.WriteLine(command);
MessageBox.Show("Send Success");
```

It works on some device.

Comment: share your code , issue is in usb or bluetooth

Comment: Code is not my concern. I may find different code for different device. I need to know is that common command for all device. Thanks Ashish for quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

> It works on some device.

You are lucky if that code ever works. After you have sent an AT command to the modem, you **MUST** wait for and parse responses from the modem until you get a [Final result code](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/at-command/info). There is absolutely no other way to handle this (but unfortunately there is a lot of dysfunctional code around the net that does not get this). For how to handle this, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16404193/23118).

Comment: Thank u for your reply. The code I used from here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38705/Send-and-Read-SMS-through-a-GSM-Modem-using-AT-Com. That is bit complex to show in here. But My above  code woks for some device.