# How can I call an "AT command" in Codesys for a GSM modem? Not standard send_sms, etc

Tags: gsm, modem, at-command, codesys

I have a GSM modem and a PLC. The PLC sees a modem (I use a *.lib and functional block "openPort"), but I don't understand how send an "AT command" to the modem, for example, "ate0".

Answer (score 0):

First, to increase your understanding of AT commands in general, read the V.[250 specification](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en). That will go a long way in making you an AT command expert.

Then for the actual implementation, I do not know Codesys, so the following is pseudo code of the structure you should have for handling AT commands:

```
the_modem = openPort();
...
// Start sending ATE0
writePort(the_modem, "ATE0\r");
do {
    line = readLinePort(the_modem);
} while (! is_final_result_code(line))
// Sending of ATE0 command finished (successfully or not)
...
closePort(the_modem);
```

Whatever you do, never, never use `delay`, `sleep` or similar as a substitute for waiting for the final result code. You can look at the code for [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) for an example for the `is_final_result_code` function (you can also compare to `isFinalResponseError` and `isFinalResponseSuccess` in [ST-Ericsson's U300 RIL](https://github.com/aferre/u300-ril/blob/master/atchannel.c), although note that `CONNECT` is not a final result code. It is an intermediate result code, so the name isFinalResponseSuccess is not 100% correct).