# How to get the output of AT command into a string in java?

Tags: java, inputstream, at-command, smslib, java-communication-api

I am trying to read the result of an AT command (command executed to do various operation to a GSM modem from console). I have seen and successfully tested using the Java OuputStream class to get the result of an AT command as output stream but what I need to do is to get the result not as outputstream but into a variable (String for now) in my class.

If it is possible to do like

```
outStream.write(("Some At command").getBytes());
```

which works fine, how can it be possibe to do something like this

```
Strign resultOfCommmand=.....result of some AT command;
```

I am trying it in this way

```
 InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(("some at commamd").getBytes());

 String result = getStringFromInputStream(is);

 System.out.println("66666666666666666666-----"+result);

/////////////////////

 private static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();

    }
```

but insted of getting the result iam getting the at command itself as a string 
 like this....
output:

```
66666666666666666666-----AT+CMGR=20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must restructure the flow in your program so that it starts by sending the AT command line, and then read back **and parse** the every single response line given back from the modem until you get a final result code. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16446523/23118) for the general outline.

Properly parsing AT command responses is not that complicated, have a look at the source code for [atinout](http://sourceforge.net/p/atinout/code/ci/master/tree/atinout.c) for an example.

Comment: Thanks your links helped me out