# Send SMS via Nokia Mobile Using AT Commands

Tags: vb.net, gsm, at-command

I'm trying to send sms with my Nokia cell phone (C1-01) using AT Commands and I can successfully send SMS with this vb.net code.

```
Button_Send_Click:

Dim SMSPort = New SerialPort
    With SMSPort
        .PortName = "COM2"
        .BaudRate = 9600
        .Parity = Parity.None
        .DataBits = 8
        .StopBits = StopBits.One
        .Handshake = Handshake.None
        .DtrEnable = True
        .RtsEnable = True
        .NewLine = vbCrLf
    End With

    SMSPort.Open()

    SMSPort.Write("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)

    SMSPort.Write("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & TextBox1.Text & Chr(34) & vbCrLf) 'TextBox1.text = Recipient mobile number and chr(34) = "
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)

    SMSPort.Write("TEST MESSAGE" & Chr(26)) 'chr(26) = →
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)

    MsgBox(SMSPort.ReadExisting())

    SMSPort.Close()
```

It's working fine for the 1st time, after fire this code I received SMS on my cell phone `TEST MESSAGE`(Brilliant)  BUT when I press send button in second time I received SMS on my cell phone which contains:
`AT+CMGF=1
AT+CMGS=+92XXYYYYYY
TEST MESSAGE`

Why in second time it's including "AT Commands i.e AT+CMGF etc.." in SMS?
How can I remove unwanted text from this?
I have also try `SMSPort.DiscardInBuffer()` and `SMSPort.DiscardOutBuffer()` Properties after opening and before closing my serial port (SMSPort) but my issue is not resolving. 
I have googled alot but all is vain, Please help me to resolve this issue.

Platform: Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 with .NET 2.0

Comment: Just curious why you are using AT commands on a Nokia phone. It will be a lot easier if you use a GSM library. I've used a couple of open source libraries and they work fine. I've also done AT commands on a microcontroller connected to a barebone GSM module and the thing is...you'll have to use a couple of delays so the GSM module can catch up with what you're sending to it :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must seriously redo your AT command handling to

- Read **and parse** the every single response line given back from the modem until you get a final result code. This applies for every single command line invocation, no exceptions whatsoever. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16446523/23118) for more details.
- Never ever call `Threading.Thread.Sleep` in any code that handles AT commands. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15591673/23118) for more details about the risk of aborting the next command.
- For `AT+CMGS` specifically you also **MUST** wait for the "\n\r> " response before sending data, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15591673/23118) (again) for more details.

Before fixing these fundamental issues you cannot expect any successful behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But it's too late and I have now working at another project. But Soon I will re-open this project and if your answer will helpful I will accept it.
@hlovdal

Answer (score 0):

OK, I came across the same issue today, and I solved it by adding "**\r\n**" to the end of the message, before sending CTRL+Z (char 26). You may try it with just "\n"

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But it's too late and I am currently working at another project. But Soon I will re-open this project and if your answer will helpful I will definitely accept it. @aly.yousuf7

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Dim SMSPort = New SerialPort
    With SMSPort
        .PortName = "COM2"
        .BaudRate = 9600
        .Parity = Parity.None
        .DataBits = 8
        .StopBits = StopBits.One
        .Handshake = Handshake.None
        .DtrEnable = True
        .RtsEnable = True
        .NewLine = vbCrLf
End With

SMSPort.Open()

SMSPort.WriteLine("AT" & Chr(13))
Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)

SMSPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" & Chr(13))
Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)

SMSPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & TextBox1.Text & Chr(34)) 
Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)

SMSPort.WriteLine("TEST MESSAGE" & Chr(26))
Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)

MsgBox(SMSPort.ReadExisting())

SMSPort.Close()
```

Add SMSPort.WriteLine("AT" & Chr(13)) and I replaced Write with WriteLine and removed vbCrlf. Also added Chr(13) to SMSPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1")