# Java Serial Communication through GSM Modem

Tags: java, serial-port

### It is in reference to the question below asked in Stack Overflow.

After doing few Try & Error, i created following code a year ago, it is working fine. It uses GSM Modem to send SMS. Your GSM Modem should be connected to your Comm Port. You would be requiring Comm.jar library to run this code, You can download it from http://llk.media.mit.edu/projects/picdev/software/javaxcomm.zip

My code is simple programmtic version of firing AT Commands. It simply fires AT Command on GSM Modem to send SMS.

```
import javax.comm.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SimpleWrite implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener
{
public void run()
{}

static Enumeration portList;
static CommPortIdentifier portId;
static String messageString = "";
static char ch = '"';
static String dest = ch + "111111111" + ch;  // 10 Digit Mobile Number.
static InputStream inputStream;

static SerialPort serialPort;
static OutputStream outputStream;

public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event)
{
    switch (event.getEventType())
    {
    case SerialPortEvent.BI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OE:
    case SerialPortEvent.FE:
    case SerialPortEvent.PE:
    case SerialPortEvent.CD:
    case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
    case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
    case SerialPortEvent.RI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
        break;
    case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
    {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        try
        {

            while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Error while reading Port " + e);
        }
        break;

    }
    } //switch
 }

  public SimpleWrite(SerialPort serial)
  {
    try
    {
        inputStream = serial.getInputStream();
        try
        {
            serial.addEventListener(this);
        }
        catch (TooManyListenersException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception in Adding Listener" + e);
        }
        serial.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception in getting InputStream" + ex);
    }

   }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String line1 = "AT+CMGF=1\r\n";
    String line2 = "AT+CMGS=" + dest + "\r\n";
    String line3 = messageString + "\r\n";
    //String line1 = "AT+CREG=2";
    //String line2 = "AT+CGREG?";

    portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    while (portList.hasMoreElements())
    {
        portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
        {
            if ( portId.getName().equals("COM11"))
            {
                System.out.println("SMS Sending....Port Found");
                try
                {
                    serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleWriteApp", 2000);
                    SimpleWrite wr = new SimpleWrite(serialPort);

                }
                catch (PortInUseException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Port In Use " + e);
                }
                try
                {
                    outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Error writing to output stream " + e);
                }
                try
                {
                serialPort.setSerialPortParams          

                (9600,
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                  SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                 SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                }
                catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e)
                {
                }
                try
                {
                    outputStream.write(line1.getBytes());
                    outputStream.write(line1.getBytes());
                    outputStream.write(line2.getBytes());
                    outputStream.write(line3.getBytes());
                    outputStream.write(26);
                    outputStream.flush();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Error writing message " + e);
                }
            }
        }
       }
     }

   /** show text in the text window
   * @param Text text string to show on the display
   */
   public static void showText(String Text)
   {
      System.out.println(Text);
    }
```

### }

I have tried the solution but its is not returning any ports in Enumeration "portlist".
and also I didn`t find any DLL in this link http://llk.media.mit.edu/projects/picdev/software/javaxcomm.zip
Please suggest how I would go on this.Whats the name of DLL so that i can proceed??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562565/how-to-get-javax-comm-api

Comment: Even after I have added Win32com.dll and Javax.comm.properties file in my Eclipse directory and also in my JRE/Lib/ext then also portlist is not getting enumerated and it keep getting false.

Comment: When you have resolved the build/run-time related problem, you ought to correct your AT command handling to read and parse responses. See this answer for instance, http://stackoverflow.com/a/20730446/23118.

Comment: Yes, Iam able to get through the Sending part of SMS through the Java Program. But not able to listen to any of the recieved messages. AT +CMGR=1 where 1 is the position of new SMS message in GSM Modem. Listening is not going good. could you help with the same

Comment: Please refer to this now : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306784/how-to-read-incoming-messages-from-gsm-modem-in-java