# Application crashes when receiving CMTI signal from gsm modem

Tags: qt, serial-port, at-command

I'm working in Qt creator c++ and linux os, and I'm trying to create program that reads and sends sms messages. Everything works fine, but when I try to read cmti signal that signals that new message is received it brakes and os sends me SIGBUS, bus error.

My code is simply:

```
port->setPortName(s);

bool status = port->open(QSerialPort::ReadWrite); 

if(status)
{
    port->setBaudRate(115200, QSerialPort::AllDirections);
    port->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    port->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);

    QByteArray in;

    if(port->waitForReadyRead(300)) 
        {
            in = port->readAll();
            while (port->waitForReadyRead(64))
            {
                in += in->readAll();
            }
        }

    //...
}
```

When modem sends cmti and port gets that signal in port->watiForReadyRead() it gives me error and never gets to port->readAll(). Also, when this error occurs it changes ttyUSB port for modem.

My best guess is that modem blocks port so my app can read. In c# in widows I have solved this by setting read timeout on serial port, but I can't do this in qt.

Can anyone help with this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must always explicitly enable all the different UR codes you want to listen to on a specific given serial interface. If you have several serial interfaces open and run `AT+CNMI=2` on one of them you cannot assume that `+CNMI: ...` will occur on any other interfaces than the on that ran the AT+CNMI command. Assume nothing is remembered if you open, close and then reopen.

So, in your code above, add a call to write AT+CNMI with the mode you want, and then [read and parse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16446523/23118) everything you get back from the moden until you get the `OK` final result code before continuing with the code expecting to receive `+CNMI: ...` UR codes. (BTW you should rather use `readLine` than `readAll` since AT command responses should always be handled line by line.)

Comment: Thanks for guidance, setting AT+CNMI=2,1,0,0,0 worked.