# VB.net sending/recieving AT commands from SIM Card

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, port, at-command

ok, so i have been using Vb for a while but brand new to communicating with devices.

I have a HP Elitebook 820  which has a SIM card slot, what id like to do is display the SIM card info - specifically the serial number. I have done a bit of searching and found lots of people talking about AT commands. after a bit more searching i gave it a try.

```
    Dim com1 As SerialPort = New System.IO.Ports.SerialPort

    com1.PortName = "COM6"

    com1.Open()

    If com1.IsOpen Then
        com1.Write("AT+CIMI")
        Dim result As String
        result = com1.ReadExisting
        MsgBox(result)
    Else
        MsgBox("port not open")
    End If
```

No Errors but just blank string returned. Could anyone help me out by letting me know, first if this even possible and second am i going about it the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Fetch a copy of the [V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en) modem standard and read at least all of chapter 5. That will teach you a lot of basic AT command handling, like for instance that an AT command line should be terminated with `\r`.

Step 2. The very best documentation is your modem manufacturer's specific documentation which you definitely should try to get hold of that, however for basic mobile phone commands like `AT+CIMI` you can use the 3GPP spec [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) as well (assuming the manufacturer has not deviated in its implementation. Sometimes they do for some commands so this is something to watch out for (hence my recommendation to first and foremost get the modem manufacturer's specific documentation). The AT+CIMI command is however so simple there is nothing to deviate from really.).

Step 3. The reception handling, e.g. `result = com1.ReadExisting` is way too simplistic. You **MUST** read and parse every single line of response from the modem until you get a Final result code back (most commonly `OK` or `ERROR`, but there are several others). Any other way cannot work reliably. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16446523/23118) for pseudo code structure of how to do it properly.