# Multiple sms send in AT commands VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, at-command, bulksms

I'm trying to send many or bulk sms using AT Command. I try send all number inside the datagrid but only first number is sending.

this is my code

```
    Dim sql As New MySqlDataAdapter("select StudentID, StudentName,StudentContact, DueDate  FROM issue inner join student on student.StudentID = issue.Student  ", conn)
     Dim ds As New DataSet
    sql.Fill(ds, 0)
    For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        Dim wholenum As String
        Dim wholesms As String
        wholenum = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2).ToString
        wholesms = "Hello " & ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1).ToString & ",  this is your Due Date  " & ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3).ToString & " pls return it on your due date"

        If SerialPort1.IsOpen Then
            Try
                With SerialPort1
                    .Write("AT" & vbCrLf)
                    .Write("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf)
                    .Write("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & wholenum & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)
                    .Write(wholesms & Chr(26))



                    MsgBox("Success sa SEND")


                    'update one 

                    'Call ConnectDatabase()
                    'com = New MySqlCommand("UPDATE issue SET Sent='1' ", conn)
                    'com.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    'Call DisconnectDatabase()

                End With

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Bad Signal or No load")
            End Try

        Else
            MsgBox("Pls insert a modem")
        End If
```

I think the looping is working 'cuz it apppears the successful message of how many inside in the datagrid view. But it only send the first number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your AT command handling significantly. First of all you need to **read and parse** everything the modem sends back to you after sending a AT command line (which by the way should be terminated with just `"\r"` and not vbCrLf).

You should never start sending a new command line before you have received the Final result code. And for `AT+CMGS` specifically you should never send the sms payload before you have received the `"\r\n >"` prefix.

These issues are covered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16446523/23118) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15591673/23118) answer. But the very first thing you should to is to read *all of the text* in chapter 5 in the [V.250 specification](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en). It is a [really important document](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33266839/23118) when working with AT commands.